# perl: How to decode hex data to integer, string?

Tags: perl

Support I have some hex raw data printed using c code with format such as “%02X”.
so they look like :

`\x00\x20\x00\x10\xfd\x02\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\xff\x02\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x05\x00\x011\x00\x01\x00\n\x00\x0240`

I want to decode them following some format like:
The first two Byte hex “\x00\x20” should be decoded to a ushort:
The following two B hex “\x00\x10” should be decoded to a ushort:
The following 8B hex “\xfd\x02\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20” should be coded to a 64 bit.
The following 8B hex “\xff\x02\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00`\x00” should be coded to a 64 bit;
The following 3 Byte Hex should be decoded to 3 char.
....

How do I implement the decoding in perl
(BTW I do not understand why there are backslash between each hex, is it how hex should be printed out)?

Answer (score 1):

`s{\\x(..)}{chr hex $1}eg;` for single bytes.
or just `unpack("v", "\x00\x20");` (see unpack function for details).

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl -w
$_ = "\x61\x62";
s{\\x(..)}{chr hex $1}eg;
print "approach1: $_\n";
$str2 = unpack("v", "\x61\x62");
print "approach2: $str2\n";

Comment: the answer is:bash-3.00# ./hex2str.pl 
approach1: ab
approach2: 25185

Comment: Indeed. And it wholly depends on what you want which approach you use. One day you say ushort (short of Perl not having "shorts" - "\x61\x62" is a string, "ab" is another string, and 25185 is a number, usually with a capacity of int), so use approach 2; the other you say "hex2str", so use appoach 1.

Answer (score 0):

1. Decode the data:

   - `s/\\x(..)/chr hex $1/eg/;`
   - Better still, assuming you have control over the C code that generates the input, get it to output binary data in the first place and avoid this step entirely.
2. Use [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) to decode the components.